# Is There a static field equivalent of extensions?

Tags: c#, generics, static, extension-methods

For a generic class, `foo<T>` I can specify methods that only are available to certain types of the class, for example

`public static void(this foo<int> val)` is a valid declaration, as is

`public static void(this foo<float> val)` and in this way, I can specify different behaviors for a generic I intend to use the same way, handling the difference between them in their individual methods. Most useful case of this is to add Arithmetic functions to Vectors, Matrices, and Sets while still having them generic. (Since there is for some god forsaken reason still no INumeric constraint to define only types which support the basic operators)

Is there an equivalent functionality for static variables. The objective being, I can accomplish the following:

`foo<int>.Zero` and `foo<float>.Zero` and have each one be different, and not conflict with each other, returning a `foo` of the appropriate type, but without throwing errors in the case where `foo<bar>.Zero` because there is no "Zero" concept for an object like `bar`

Comment: what would you expect the result to be? `null`?

Comment: @flakes I wouldn't expect there to be a result at all. There should be no static field `foo<bar>.Zero`. Basically, I don't want to have anywhere in my class `public static foo<T> Zero => new Foo<T>()`

I want `Zero` to be defined only for the types of `foo` for which its relevant, ie int, float, double.

Comment: So I think you could do this for an instance method through extension methods, but not a static as it requires an instance. Someone correct me if I'm wrong. See here for an example using instance methods https://arbel.net/2007/11/22/c-partial-specialization-with-extension-methods/

Comment: The answer is no, not as you want it. You could constrain to a struct, yet even that isn't really fool proof. However you could validate the right hand side with static method overloads. However, im not really sure you will get a satisfying solution to this

Comment: @TheGeneral No, it's not satisfying. I wish Microsoft would better support this. It's ridiculous I have to declare my type specific methods in an extension to begin with. FeelsBadMan

Comment: @Azeranth i am not really sure why there is no constraint for a simple BCL numeric type or a marker interface called (INumeric), I guess because operators and trying to keep a modicum of type safety (just a guess)

Comment: Yes, there is nothing inbuilt to provide this.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not provide with syntax that allow you to define field for property extensions, or static extensions for classes.

To achieve this, you should use some static property like `foo.ZeroOfFloat` as some C# standard APIs are defined like that.

It looks very pretty and cleaned when you are using more generic things, but this is not the correct use case of generic.

"Generic" means that it is general, for type irrelavent use, therefore it is different from template definitions in C++ that supports specialization. Technically, generic definitions in C# is compiled and delivered as IL, rather than as source code in C++, which means the compilation happens before a certain type is plugged into a generic definition and there cannot be a specialization for a single type.

Although there are some generic constraints for reference types, value types, delegates, or native structs etc., that limit the use of generic definition to some type of types. This disallows some use cases, rather than supporting something.

Although you could make use of that there could be different extension methods on a generic type that is closed with different type arguments (that gives you a feeling of template specialization), that is not by design.

Do not achieve a specific logic in generic definition. Definitions like `ZeroOfFloat` are never bad practices.

Comment: So, no, Generics are not exclusively for type irrelevant handling.